# how to store string into array in c# web

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, c#-4.0, webmethod

```
  [code="C#"]
    int counter=0;
    string filename = "Folio-Mapping-Form-" + myinvestorid.Value +".pdf";
        counter++;
        for (int i = 0; i <=counter; i++)
        {
            appendfile +=filename;
            htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToFile(htmlString, baseUrl, 
              filePath + filename);

        }
```

here I having string filename which is having many filename but I want to store filename into array.how can I store filename into array

Comment: have a look at this.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question .Could  you paste more code？Based on what I understand，try to use string[] or use `List<string>` then call  ToArray method.